# I am implementing admob rewarded ADS in my App but is it correct to lock one of the features on the main menu and unlock them on watching the video

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, policy, rewardedvideoad

I am implementing admob rewarded ads in my app but i am not sure if its correct according to the policy to lock on of the features of the app on the main menu and unlock them on watch the video ? is it ok to do so ? is it according to the policy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google's AdMob policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You first read all the **AdMob** ads related policies and confirm.

AdMob provides AdListener. You can set this listener with AdView and you can use it's override methods. `AdListener` listener will be executed when any action perform with `AdView`. Like when Ads Open, Ads Load, Ads Closed everytime related method will execured by listener.

Like,

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener());
```

please check [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener) link for more detail about `AdListener`.